# Eigenvectors of hermitian matrix are not coming out to be orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hermitian-matrices

I have the following hermitian matrix before me:
\begin{pmatrix}2 &1+i\\ 1-i& 3\end{pmatrix}
I calculated its characteristic polynomial as $k^2-5k+4$ which has $1$ and $4$ as its roots.
Eigenvectors corresponding to these two eigenvalues are \begin{pmatrix}-(1+i) &1 \end{pmatrix} and \begin{pmatrix}1 &1-i\end{pmatrix}
But these are not orthogonal. Why is it so? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: make sure you are considering in the complex inner product  i.e.  $<v,w>=v \bar{w}$

Comment: @Moo The second eigenvector of yours can be obtained by multiplying mine one by $1+i$. Even then the vectors are not orthogonal.

Comment: @Brozovic Could you please elaborate on complex inner product? I have no knowledge about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Eigen values are $4,1$ and eigenvectors are $V_1=\begin{bmatrix} 1+i \\2 \end{bmatrix}$ and $V_2=\begin{bmatrix} -1-i \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$, then
$V_1^{\dagger} V_2=0$, $\dagger$ means conjugate and transpose.